# how to aggregate by month/year in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to count records and group by zip code, month, year.  My current sql:

```
select
Property_Zip
  , count(Distinct Listing_Tracking_ID)   LISTINGCOUNT
  , round(avg( Current_Listing_Price), 2) AVGPRICE
  , FORMAT_DATE('%m', Current_Original_Listing_Date) MONTH
  , FORMAT_DATE('%Y', Current_Original_Listing_Date) YEAR
from `PROJECT.DS.TABLE`
group by Property_Zip
  , FORMAT_DATE('%m', Current_Original_Listing_Date)
  , FORMAT_DATE('%Y', Current_Original_Listing_Date)
```

My problem is results are coming up as nulls for month and year.  My problem is I can't find a month() function in Standard SQL.

How do I do this?
thanks!

#UPdate 1
Tried this:

```
select
Property_Zip
  , count(Distinct Listing_Tracking_ID)   LISTINGCOUNT
  , round(avg( Current_Listing_Price), 2) AVGPRICE
  , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Current_Original_Listing_Date) MONTH
  , EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Current_Original_Listing_Date) YEAR
from `mother-216719.VALUATION.MLS`
group by Property_Zip, DATE_TRUNC(Current_Original_Listing_Date, MONTH)
```

error: SELECT list expression references column Current_Original_Listing_Date which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [5:24]

Comment: you cannot combine different approaches from my answer in one /same query  - either you using EXTRACT or DATE_TRUNC!!!!

Comment: ok.  how do I get the month and year while grouping by month and year?

Comment: see in my answer  - i just added it - sorry I thought it is obvious so I skipped to show the whole query initially

Answer (score 0):

You should use EXTRACT function (assuming that `Current_Original_Listing_Date` field is of DATE data type

```
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Current_Original_Listing_Date)    

EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Current_Original_Listing_Date)
```

So, your query can looks like

```
select
  Property_Zip
  , count(Distinct Listing_Tracking_ID)   LISTINGCOUNT
  , round(avg( Current_Listing_Price), 2) AVGPRICE
  , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Current_Original_Listing_Date) MONTH
  , EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Current_Original_Listing_Date) YEAR
from `PROJECT.DS.TABLE`
group by Property_Zip
  , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Current_Original_Listing_Date)
  , EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Current_Original_Listing_Date)
```

As alternative  - you can use DATE_TRUNC function to truncate date field to MONTH   -  DATE_TRUNC(Current_Original_Listing_Date, MONTH) - in this case you will need to group by just one field

in this case it will be

```
select
  Property_Zip
  , count(Distinct Listing_Tracking_ID)   LISTINGCOUNT
  , round(avg( Current_Listing_Price), 2) AVGPRICE
  , DATE_TRUNC(Current_Original_Listing_Date, MONTH) YEAR_MONTH
from `PROJECT.DS.TABLE`
group by Property_Zip,
  DATE_TRUNC(Current_Original_Listing_Date, MONTH)
```